# How to get use papaparse with remote link in react-native?

Tags: csv, react-native, papaparse

what I have tried is as following.  However, it kept show the error: 'Synchronous http requests are not supported'.

```
    import * as Papa from 'papaparse';

    componentDidMount(){
    let csvUrl = 'http://www.sample-videos.com/csv/Sample-Spreadsheet-10-rows.csv';

        Papa.parse(csvUrl, {
            download: true,
          complete: function(results) {
            console.log('papa results: ', results);
          }
        });
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.